# Find if my branch conflicts with any remote branch

Tags: git, conflict, git-merge, git-rebase, pull-request

Our company works with branch-per-feature approach. So each developer creates a new branch, hacks and pushes to shared-repo on server. The server repos's post-receive hook will trigger the pull-request!

Before I allow user to push to server I want to check if his/her branch gives conflict with any unmerged-with-master branch on server!

Currently I gave a canned command with fetches all pull-request branches from server and rebases the developers branch against each one of em and finds if it gives conflict!

Problem:
 1. The process of rebasing/merging with each branch takes ages
 2. It keeps changing the working tree continuously

Am I doing it wrong or is there any other approach to find if developers branch will conflict with any pull request branch on server!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Before I allow user to push to server I want to check if his/her branch gives conflict with any unmerged-with-master branch on server!

In my opinion, that is one *very* incorrect strategy. You have to realize that conflicts are a normal part of git, that there is nothing unholy about them, and that no matter how much you try to avoid them, they will happen one time or the other.

For example, if there are 2 features, both of which modify a file at the same line number with different lines of code, git will definitely end up throwing a conflict - there is no way you can avoid that.

Now because you will have this *check no conflict* script, you will never be able to push the second branch unless the first one is merged. An absolute waste of time and developer productivity.

Also, you are forgetting that developers may push their branches even if the branch is not merge ready, you would end up unable to that as well. If two or more developers are collaborating, they simpley wouldn't be able to becuase they can't push because their branch is in conflict wth some other branch

In case you have a sufficiently large dev team (say 10), with sufficiently large number of branches (say 100), you are basically going to end up comparing with 100 branches, on every push by every dev. Imagine 10 devs pushing in just twice in a day, and you are already onto 2000 possible points of conflicts between different sets of developers. People might easily end up spending more time resolving conflicts prematurely then devloping.

---

So how to do this in a saneful way?

Basically, don't try to prematurely avoid future conflicts.

Make one of the branches the reference - check only against `master` branch and make sure that there is absolutely no conflict with this at time of merge.

Every time a merge is to be done, check for a conflict with the master and merge only when there is no conflict. If there is a conflict, ask the request/branch owner to fetch the updated master, rebase his branch, resolve the conflicts and push back again.

Comment: Got you point! Also I am not checking with "every unmerged branch". I am checking only with every-umerged-pull-request.

Also, one usecase for me checking this is the idea that if two people are changing the same line in same file there is a 90% probability that their code is dependent and hence I want to tell the developer in advance that "boss, someone has done something that you might want to account for in your code". However I do allow the developer to push the code anyway!